# Power series approximation for $\ln((1+x)^{(1+x)}) + \ln((1-x)^{(1-x)})$ to calculate $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n+1)} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

**Problem**

Approximate $f(x) = \ln((1+x)^{(1+x)}) + \ln((1-x)^{(1-x)})$  and then calculate $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n+1)} $

---

**My attempt**

Let
$$f(x) = \ln((1+x)^{(1+x)}) + \ln((1-x)^{(1-x)}) \iff $$
$$f(x) =  (1+x)\ln(1+x) + (1-x)\ln(1-x) \quad $$

We know that the basic Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ is

$$ \ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \quad (1)$$

As far as $\ln(1-x)$ is concerned

$$y(x) = \ln(1-x) \iff y'(x) = \frac{-1}{1-x} = - \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \text{ (geometric series)} \iff$$
$$y(x) = \int -\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n  = - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \quad (2)$$

Therefore from $f(x), (1), (2)$ we have:

$$ f(x) = (1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - (1-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \iff$$

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{n+2} + (-1)^n x^{n+1} - x^{n+1} }{n+1} $$

---

**Why I hesitate**

It all makes sense to me up to this point. But the exercise has a follow up sub-question that requires to find:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n+1)} $$

I am pretty sure that this sum is somehow connected with the previous power series that we've found, but I can't find a way to calculate it, so I assume that I have made a mistake.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the last line above "Why I hesitate", this is not the way you collect terms in a power series. You should collect terms in powers of x. That will make things much clearer. (For example, it should be in the form $\sum c_nx^n$, where $c_n$ are coefficients that do not involve $x$)

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thanks Benjamin, it makes sense!

Comment: @BenjaminWang I tried to re-write it in terms of $x$ (edited the answer), but I can't get rid of that $(-1)^n$. Any ideas?

Comment: And still is doesn't look like $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(2n+1)} $ at all

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{n+2} + (-1)^n x^{n+1} - x^{n+1} }{n+1} $$

Supposing the above is right. We want to change the $n+2$'s to $n+1$'s. To do this, write, by letting $m+1 = n+2$,

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2x^{n+2}}{n+1}  = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{2x^{m+1}}{m} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x^{n+1}}{n},$$

where, in the last step, we simply changed the dummy variable $m$ to $n$.

I haven't read it very carefully, but sometimes you can get $2n+1$ in the denominator when you're only summing over odd integers.

**SPOILER**

> [image]

Comment: I will work on it and accept it as an answer if I figure it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have edited it. See the spoiler if you want

Answer (score 3):

Summing $$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(2n+1)}=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=2 [1/2-1/3+ 1/4-1/5_....]$$ $$\implies S=2(1-\ln 2).$$

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach for the second part:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} S &=& \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}=2\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)=2\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{2n-1}-x^{2n}\right)\,dx\\&=&2\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(x^{2n-1}-x^{2n}\right)\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-x^2}{1-x^2}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x}\,dx \\ &=&2\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\,dx = 2\left[x-\log(x+1)\right]_{0}^{1} = \color{red}{2(1-\log 2)}. \end{eqnarray*} $$